# Fragments take time to load layout in viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have implemented a view pager in my app.Inside getItem method I returned a  fragment.It wroks fine. But it takes some time(approximately: 1 sec) to load the fragment's layout. Inside onCreateView method of fragment, I inflate layout and return. If I change to different layout file it works fine(Don't paused or take any time).

I don't know how to overcome this issue.I can use AsyncTask if problem is due to other operation. But for only layout inflate I don't know why and how should I use AsyncTask. My viewpager items are small in number (3 or 5). I am struggling with this for few days and overall performance of app become poor.

Also I assume that calling fragment from viewpager is correct because I tried with defferent layout file and it works fine.

From Fragment:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.specific_current_details,
            container, false);
   //        init();

    return rootView;
}
```

From logcat I find this :

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 6889K, 16% free 48743K/57424K, paused 3ms+37ms, total 109ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 62ms
D/dalvikvm:  GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 16% free 48794K/57424K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: You should start by optimizing your layouts. a second to load is too much

Comment: How should i do that. If i have only one fragment than also same thing happens.